# let function return template type

Tags: c++

I had the following function

```
SlabWallConnectionEvent* createObservedEvent(SlabWallConnectionEvent::Data* pEventData)
{
    assert(pEventData != nullptr);
    return SlabWallConnectionEvent::create(pEventData->m_wall, pEventData->m_slab);
}
```

Then I was able to make a more general template from it with template specification.

.h file

```
template <class ObservedEventType, class ObservedEventDataType>
void createObservedEvent(ObservedEventType*& pEvent,ObservedEventDataType* pEventData);
```

.cpp file

```
template<>
void createObservedEvent<SlabWallConnectionEvent, SlabWallConnectionEvent::Data>
                (SlabWallConnectionEvent*& pEvent, SlabWallConnectionEvent::Data* pEventData)
{
    assert(pEventData != nullptr);
    pEvent = SlabWallConnectionEvent::create(pEventData->m_wall, pEventData->m_slab);
}
```

This works perfectly for me but I am not too pleased with the reference to the raw pointer. Is it possible to change it to something like this:

.h file

```
template <class ObservedEventType, class ObservedEventDataType>
ObservedEventType* createObservedEvent(ObservedEventDataType* pEventData);
```

.cpp file

```
template<>
SlabWallConnectionEvent* createObservedEvent<SlabWallConnectionEvent, SlabWallConnectionEvent::Data>
                (bim_ui::SlabWallConnectionEvent::Data* pEventData)
{
    assert(pEventData != nullptr);
    return bim_ui::SlabWallConnectionEvent::create(pEventData->m_wall, pEventData->m_slab);
}
```

When I try to use this I get following error:

```
Error   1   error C2783: 'ObservedEventType 
*createObservedEvent(ObservedEventDataType *)' : could not deduce template 
argument for 'ObservedEventType'
```

**Edit**
I use this function in a template function

```
template <class ObservedEventType>
void CmdBimDrag::observeConnectionEvent(ObservedEventData* pObservedEvent){
    ...
    if (pCurrentEvent == nullptr)
        createObservedEvent(pCurrentEvent, pEventData);
    ...
}
```

and that function gets called like this

```
observeConnectionEvent<SlabWallConnectionEvent>((*pObservedEventData).get());
```

**Edit2**

[Jonas' answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43273388/3681671) first part works just specifying the template type is enough:

```
createObservedEvent<SlabWallConnectionEvent>(pEventData);
```

However using auto does not seem to warrant a removal of the return type spefication:

.h file

```
template <class ObservedEventType, class ObservedEventDataType>
auto createObservedEvent(ObservedEventDataType* pEventData) -> ObservedEventType*;
```

.cpp file

```
template<>
auto createObservedEvent<SlabWallConnectionEvent, SlabWallConnectionEvent::Data>
    (SlabWallConnectionEvent::Data* pEventData) -> SlabWallConnectionEvent*
{
    assert(pEventData != nullptr);
    return SlabWallConnectionEvent::create(pEventData->m_wall, pEventData->m_slab);
}
```

This code compiles with the template specification but just calling:

```
createObservedEvent(pEventData);
```

Still gives the first error about not being able to deduce the type.

Comment: See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file?rq=1)

Comment: since the first template parameter cannot be determined from the call location (it's only used as the return type), you need to specify that template parameter explicitly when you call the function.

Comment: The call with the second solution would be `auto* pEvent = createObservedEvent<ObservedEventType>(pEventData)` instead of `createObservedEvent(&pEvent , pEventData);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be specific about the return type:

```
createObservedEvent<SlabWallConnectionEvent>(pEventData);
```

Here is an [example](http://ideone.com/sD0yJP), using simpler types.

Alternatively, you could use `auto` as the return type and not include a template parameter for the return type. Online example [here](http://ideone.com/DUDg8W).

Comment: using auto does not warrant a removal of the return type.
I've updated my answer with my current code

Comment: Using `auto` you do not need a specific return type if it can be deduced by the compiler.

Comment: Seems like it can't in my case but then again I admit I have a pretty dicey setup. I've had to sidestep not being able to do template specification of member functions and not being able to forward declare internal classes.
Overall I'm happy with the result but this was a last refinement.

Answer (score 2):

When you have this:

```
template <class ObservedEventType, class ObservedEventDataType>
void createObservedEvent(ObservedEventType*& pEvent,ObservedEventDataType* pEventData);
```

and call it like this:

```
int *ip;
double *dp;
createObservedEvent(ip, dp);
```

the compiler can deduce that `ObservedEventType` must be `int` and `ObservedEventDataType` must be `double`, so it instantiates `createObservedEvent<int, double>` and calls it.

When you use this instead:

```
template <class ObservedEventType, class ObservedEventDataType>
ObservedEventType* createObservedEvent(ObservedEventDataType* pEventData);
```

and call it like

```
double *dp;
int *ip = createObservedEvent(dp);
```

the compiler can deduce that `ObservedEventDataType` must be a `double`, but it cannot deduce what `ObservedEventType` should be (because the return type of a function and the type of the variable don't need to match exactly and are not used for deduction).

To solve this you can manually tell the compiler what `ObservedEventType` should be like this:

```
double *dp;
int *ip = createObservedEvent<int>(dp);
```

Now it knows the first template parameter `ObservedEventType` is `int`, because you said so, and `ObservedEventDataType` gets deduced to be `double`.

---

You also seem to be trying to put declarations for your templates in the header and the definition into the .cpp which [generally doesn't work](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl).